# Case-Insensitive Maps?

Tags: map, sobject, sobjectfield

How is it that describes seem to return case-insensitive maps? For instance, if I create a new custom setting, the following succeeds:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> fields1 = SObjectType.MySetting__c.fields.getMap();
system.assert(fields1.containsKey('Id'));
```

yet the following fails:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> fields2 = new Map<String, SObjectField>();
fields2.putAll(SObjectType.MySetting__c.fields.getMap());
system.assert(fields2.containsKey('Id'));
```

However, their keysets are the same, as the following will pass:

```
system.assertEquals(fields1.keySet(), fields2.keySet());
```

In both cases, the keyset is:

> ["id","isdeleted","name","setupownerid","createddate","createdbyid","lastmodifieddate","lastmodifiedbyid","systemmodstamp"]

Clearly, only the lower case version of the string `'id'` is in the map.

The same behavior seems to hold for `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`:

```
system.assert(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('ACCOUNT'));
```

The above described behavior seems to violate the basics of how maps work in `Apex`. Is this in fact the same data structure? Can it be constructed by hand? It would potentially be useful, for instance, in parsing parameters on a page or REST service without needing to do some sort of loop through the keys with a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs outline the behaviour of the DescribeFieldResult map.  See [Accessing All Field Describe Results for an sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm)

There's a note saying:

> The value type of this map is not a field describe result. Using the describe results would take too many system resources.
>   Instead, it is a map of tokens that you can use to find the appropriate field. After you determine the field, generate the describe
>   result for it.

It has the unique behaviour of:

> - It is dynamic, that is, it is generated at runtime on the fields for that sObject.
> - All field names are case insensitive.
> - The keys use namespaces as required.
> - The keys reflect whether the field is a custom object.

My understanding is that the keys are the tokens that have this unique behaviour, however in the second example, you're explicitly instantiating a new `Map<String, String>` with the DescribeFieldResult map in it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, describe maps break the usual case sensitivity rules. They are magical in nature. No, you can't directly replicate the behavior. You could use a wrapper class to store and retrieve only lowercase values using equals and hashCode method overrides, but you cannot construct a native map that's case insensitive.