# How to check if SObject has certain field?

Tags: apex, sobject, fields, describesobject

I hope you'll help me to solve my problem :)

I've written a class that check if a Sobject has a field of a certain name

```
public static boolean hasSObjectField(String fieldName, SObject so){
    return so.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains(fieldName);
}
```

It works very fine, but there is one fault: it does not check system fields such as, for example, `OwnerId`.

Can you tell me what I've done wrong?

Regards!

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include specific combinations you expect to exist that are failing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the keys in the map are in lower case for some reason. I get a positive result for ownerid but not for OwnerId. I checked for our account object and all the keys in the map are lowercase.

This i think should fix it:

```
public static boolean hasSObjectField(String fieldName, SObject so){
            return so.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains(fieldName.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: The describe maps are [case-insensitive](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102302/case-insensitive-maps).

Comment: Probably should delete this particular answer since case-sensitivity is unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this correctly. I tried this in the developer console and the solution seems to work. As the OP posts i can't find OwnerId for account but i can find ownerid.  Do you think the OP has a different problem? (Of course i'll delete my answer as soon i understand)

Comment: Fair enough. Hmm...I'll take a look. Are other custom fields still behaving in a case-insensitive manner? Perhaps they tweaked the magic and simply didn't tell us...

Comment: @adrianlarson - ah -- but `contains()` is a case sensitive method; it is `get` on the map's key that is case insensitive, no?

Comment: Nope. Try it yourself: `system.debug(SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().containsKey('OWNERID'));`

Comment: Running this code in the debugger:
`Type t = Type.forName('Account');
SObject lObj = (SObject) t.newInstance();
System.debug('Account Fields'+lObj.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());`

All values from keySet() are lowercase:
`11:47:00:029 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|Account Fields{accountnumber, accountsource, annualrevenue, billingaddress, billingcity, billingcountry, billinggeocodeaccuracy, billinglatitude, billinglongitude, billingpostalcode, ...}`

So the solution makes sense.

Comment: Interesting.  Using the `m.containsKey()` where `m` is a `Map` is case-insensitive, however once you grab `m.keySet()` you are  back to case sensitive because you are operating on the string values of the `Set` and don't have access to the `containsKey()` method.  And per the example above, the values of the set are all lcase.

Answer (score 1):

If you use dynamic SOQL and just wanna check results without try/catch or going thru metadata describe, you can use [SObject.isSet() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'll just go ahead and write the code, assuming the field does exist, and catch the exception if it doesn't.  e.g.

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate))) {
    try {
        for(SObject o : Trigger.new) {
            Id ownerId = null;
            String s = String.valueOf(o.get('OwnerId'));
            if(s != null && s.startsWith('005')) {
                ownerId = (Id)s;
            }
            if(ownerId != (Id)o.get('Owner__c') ) {
                o.put('Owner__c',ownerId);
            }
        }
    }
    // if the field does not exist, an exception will be thrown
    catch(SObjectException ex) {
        System.debug(ex);
    } 
}
```

In most cases this is much faster, since presumably you are using fields that should exist and this is just to handle the niche scenarios.

If you really do need to check the field say because you are building up a field map for a custom query, then the previous answer works fine.