# Is the field describe result map a special type of Map?

Tags: apex, map

I read in [Accessing All Field Describe Results for an sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm):

> Use the field describe result's getMap method to return a map that
>   represents the relationship between all the field names (keys) and the
>   field tokens (values) for an sObject.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
```

> The map has the following characteristics:
>
> All field names are **case insensitive.**

While the documentation for [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) says:

> Map keys of type String are **case-sensitive**.

### QUESTION

Is the field describe result map a special type of Map? It's quite frustrating to have one type of Map in apex to behave differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/102302/2995

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the object oriented "is a" sense, at least at compile time, they both support these [Map methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm). But the implementing class might be this for the describe map:

```
Map<String, String> m = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

and this for most other maps:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Other languages would make the distinction between interface and implementation a bit clearer by providing the contract (the methods) in an interface.

I agree being case insensitive in some places but not in others can be confusing.

Comment: +1 It'd be incredibly nice if they gave **us** the option to write case-insensitive maps without writing an entire wrapper class dedicated to that purpose.

Comment: @sfdcfox Agreed. Or Generic types so you don't have to keep re-implementing for various types.